# Get Segmentation Fault Occasionally

Tags: c++

I am trying to make a random number generator for a uni project.

I am trying to implement a function to get the period of this list of numbers generated (how long before the numbers start to repeat).

When I compile this and run it  it returns 507 (which is the correct period).

Yet about 50% of the time it returns a Segmentation Fault.
Any idea what is happening:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<vector>
#include<math.h>
#include<ctime>

using namespace std;

class Random
{
public:
// Constructor
Random(int a, int b, int m)
{
    this->setMagicNumbers(a,b,m);
}

// Function to set the magic numbers of the random number generator
void setMagicNumbers(int a, int b, int m)
{
    this->A = a;
    this->B = b;
    this->M = m;
}

// Function that returns a list of uniformly distributed random numbers
vector<double> GetUniform(int N, double initialValue = time(0))
{
    double currentNumber = initialValue;
    vector<double> RandomNumbers;
    for(int i = 0; i <= N; i++)
    {
        currentNumber = fmod((this->A*currentNumber) + this->B, this->M);
        RandomNumbers.push_back(currentNumber / this->M); // The number is normalised here
    }
    return RandomNumbers;
}

private:
int A, B, M;
};

class NumberList
{
public:
// Function to add an element to the list
void push(double x)
{
    this->v.push_back(x);
}

// Function to pop an element off the list
double pop()
{
    if(v.size() > 0)
    {
        int popped = v.back();
        v.pop_back();
        return popped;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Cannot pop element off empty list." << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    return 0;
}

// Function to get the value at a given location on the list
double getAt(int i)
{
    return this->v[i];
}

    // Function to set the value at a given location on the list
void setAt(int i, double value)
{
    this->v[i] = value;
}

// Function to find the size of the list
unsigned int size()
{
    return this->v.size();
}

// Function to get the vector itself
vector<double> getvector()
{
    return this->v;
}

// Function to set the value of the vector itself
void setVector(vector<double> vec)
{
    this->v = vec;
}

// Function to print the list of numbers as coordinates to a data file
void printCoordinates()
{
        ofstream data("coordinates.dat");
        for(unsigned int i = 0; i <= this->v.size(); i++)
        {
                data << this->v[i] <<  " " << this->v[i + 1] <<  "\n";
        }
        data.close();
}

// Function to print the list of numbers to the terminal
void print()
{
        for(unsigned int i = 0; i <= this->v.size(); i++)
        {
                cout << this->v[i] << endl;
        }
}

// Function to get the period of the list of numbers
int getPeriod()
{
    int i = 2;
    while(true)
    {
        if(isPeriod(i) == true)
        {
            return i;
        }
        else
        {
            i = i + 1;
        }
    }
}

private:
// Vector to hold the values for the list
vector<double> v;

// Function to test if 'i' is the period of the list
bool isPeriod(int i)
{
    for(int j = 0; j != (i-1); j++)
    {
        if(this->getAt(j) != this->getAt(i + j))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
};

int main()
{
Random RandNumGenerator(100,104001,714025);                // Create a new random number generator with given magic numbers
NumberList numbers;                                        // Create a blank list of numbers
numbers.setVector(RandNumGenerator.GetUniform(10000));     // Add 10000 random numbers to the list
numbers.printCoordinates();                                // Print out the random numbers as coordinates to a data file
cout << numbers.getPeriod() << endl;                       // Print out the period of the random number list
return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line could cause a problem

```
for(unsigned int i = 0; i <= this->v.size(); i++)
```

With it you are using size as the last index, which is overflow, try changing it for this:

EDIT: change for this actually

```
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < this->v.size()-1; i++)
```

On the loop you are accessing the i+1 th element of the vector.

EDIT:

This probably wouldn't cause a crash but instead of creating N elements you are creating N+1

```
for(int i = 0; i <= N; i++)
```

Change if for this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
```

EDIT:
With fixes

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<vector>
#include<math.h>
#include<ctime>

using namespace std;

class Random
{
public:
// Constructor
Random(long a, long b, long m)
{
    this->setMagicNumbers(a,b,m);
}

// Function to set the magic numbers of the random number generator
void setMagicNumbers(long a, long b, long m)
{
    this->A = a;
    this->B = b;
    this->M = m;
}

// Function that returns a list of uniformly distributed random numbers
vector<double> GetUniform(int N, double initialValue = time(0))
{
    double currentNumber = initialValue;
    vector<double> RandomNumbers;
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        currentNumber = fmod((this->A*currentNumber) + this->B, this->M);
        RandomNumbers.push_back(currentNumber / this->M); // The number is normalised here
    }
    return RandomNumbers;
}

private:
long A, B, M;
};

class NumberList
{
public:
// Function to add an element to the list
void push(double x)
{
    this->v.push_back(x);
}

// Function to pop an element off the list
double pop()
{
    if(v.size() > 0)
    {
        int popped = v.back();
        v.pop_back();
        return popped;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Cannot pop element off empty list." << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    return 0;
}

// Function to get the value at a given location on the list
double getAt(int i)
{
    return this->v[i];
}

    // Function to set the value at a given location on the list
void setAt(int i, double value)
{
    this->v[i] = value;
}

// Function to find the size of the list
unsigned int size()
{
    return this->v.size();
}

// Function to get the vector itself
vector<double> getvector()
{
    return this->v;
}

// Function to set the value of the vector itself
void setVector(vector<double> vec)
{
    this->v = vec;
}

// Function to print the list of numbers as coordinates to a data file
void printCoordinates()
{
        ofstream data("coordinates.dat");
        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < this->v.size()-1; i++)
        {
                data << this->v[i] <<  " " << this->v[i + 1] <<  "\n";
        }
        data.close();
}

// Function to print the list of numbers to the terminal
void print()
{
        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < this->v.size(); i++)
        {
                cout << this->v[i] << endl;
        }
}

// Function to get the period of the list of numbers
int getPeriod()
{
    int i = 2;
    while(true)
    {
        if(isPeriod(i) == true)
        {
            return i;
        }
        else
        {
            i = i + 1;
        }
    }
}

private:
// Vector to hold the values for the list
vector<double> v;

// Function to test if 'i' is the period of the list
bool isPeriod(int i)
{
    std::cout << "trying period " << i << endl;
    if (i >= v.size()) return true;
    for(int j = 0; j < v.size()-1; j++)
    {
        if(this->getAt(j) == this->getAt(i + j))
        {
            std::cout << "value at j " << this->getAt(j) << "value at i+j " << this->getAt(i+j) <<endl;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
};

int main()
{
Random RandNumGenerator(100,104001,714025);                // Create a new random number generator with given magic numbers
NumberList numbers;                                        // Create a blank list of numbers
numbers.setVector(RandNumGenerator.GetUniform(10000));     // Add 10000 random numbers to the list
numbers.printCoordinates();                                // Print out the random numbers as coordinates to a data file
cout << numbers.getPeriod() << endl;                       // Print out the period of the random number list
return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have changed that with no effect unfortunatly.

Comment: The functions that I think cause the problem are int getPeriod() and bool isPeriod(int i) as they calculate the period. Sometimes they stop at 507 and say that is the period. other times it goes past and cannot fin the period (I guess thats where the error comes from)

Comment: On printCoordinates(), are you trying to print the numbers in pairs?, if so then also change "i++" for "i+=2"

Comment: Ok changed according to your last edit. complied fine. ran twice and got 507. then the following 5 runs gave a segmantation fault

Comment: On printCoordinates() I am printing them in pairs with a overlap so: (1,2) (2,3) (3,4) ect

Comment: On using cout during the period functions on some runs I get:
...
Is the period 505...NO    
Is the period 506...NO    
Is the period 507...YES    
Period: 507    

Other times I get:    
...    
Is the period 505...NO    
Is the period 506...NO    
Is the period 507...NO    
Is the period 508...NO    
Is the period 509...NO    
...    
...    
Is the period 144766...NO    
Segmentation Fault

Comment: On this line if(this->getAt(j) != this->getAt(i + j)), "i+j" is very likely to be a number bigger than the biggest index. As a matter of fact, I think that what you want to do is "i-j", that way you go through all the elements before i. Please edit the question with the updated code.

Comment: changin i+j with i-j makes all resluta a segmantation fault. The reason i have i+j is that: let's say i am testing to see if i = 4 is the period. I will want to compare v[0] with v[4],  v[1] with v[5], v[2] with v[6], v[3] with v[7]. Or more genaraly v[j] with v[j+i]

Comment: I think I understand now your logic, but i+j cant be bigger than v.size() - 1, so try it with for(int j = 0; j != v.size()-1; j++). It's gotta work :)

Comment: Still it only prodeces a segmentation falut :(

Comment: Let's move this to the chat, or the moderators will close the question, go to this room http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18224/telerik-openaccess-orm

Answer (score 0):

Played around with this a bit and I initially thought that your vector of doubles was somehow getting corrupted. I found that if you size it to the exact value that you want - which is a known value - the seg faults stop:

```
vector<double> RandomNumbers(N); // In GetUniform()
```

Running it through `gdb` was inconclusive as it looked as if the stack was getting corrupted. I also found that when I changed the `push_back()` just to take 0:

```
RandomNumbers.push_back(0.0);
```

instead of the normalised number, even without the initial size for the vector (above) it worked fine, suggesting an issue with one of the variables being used.

I also found that if I set `currentNumber` to 1, say, instead of calling `fmod()` - even with everything as it originally was, I got no seg faults:

```
currentNumber = 1;
```

This kind of suggests that it might be something to do with the use of `fmod()`

Interestingly, I then took out the call to `push_back` completely and found that it *still* had segfaults. Sorry I can't be much more help than that, but it certainly looks as if some kind of corruption is happening somewhere in this area.

Answer (score 0):

In `C++` index of array and `vector` will be from 0..size - 1, and you misused it all over your code(inside `GetUniform`, inside `printCoordinates`, ...) and beside that in `printCoordinates` you written `this->v[i + 1]` at last it will be converted to `this->v[this->v.size() + 1]` that is 2 index after last valid index.

But I think source of your error is in `getPeriod` and `isPeriod`, look at it you start from 0 to `i - 1` and check if that index match item at index `i + j`, so if `i` become `size() - 1` and size be 500, then in worse case you are accessing `v[499 + 498]` that is really large than last valid index and you certainly get a segmentation fault. Now to solve it check your index and never go beyond end of the `vector` size, that mean you should never use index > `v.size() - 1`